# log4j.properties file - multiple loggers in same class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to have two different `log4j` loggers in my application, and for there to be no "overlap" between the content they write to their respect logs.

For example:

- Logger1 writes INFO events related to one set of system events
- Logger2 writes INFO events related to another set of system events
- No entry should appear in the log twice

My log4j.properties is as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.xdasLogger=DEBUG, xdas

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.xdas=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.xdas.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xdas.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

My Java code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(Client.class
            .getResource("/log4j.properties"));
    xdasLogger = Logger.getLogger("xdasLogger");
    logger = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);

    logger.info("normal");
    xdasLogger.info("xdas");
}
```

But my console output is as follows:

```
normal
2012-06-28 09:52:44,580 INFO  xdasLogger - xdas
xdas
```

Note that "xdas" is logged by both `logger` and `xdasLogger`, which is undesirable.

Does anyone know what changes I need to put into my log4j.properties to change the console output to the following?

```
normal
2012-06-28 09:52:44,580 INFO  xdasLogger - xdas
```

**Solution (taken from accepted answer):**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.xdasLogger=DEBUG, xdas

log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
log4j.additivity.xdasLogger=false

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.xdas=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.xdas.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xdas.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try setting the additivity of the loggers to false. This will avoid the propagation to the rootLogger.

```
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
log4j.additivity.xdasLogger=false
```

Comment: Your solution seems absolutely correct but isn't working for me. I added these lines to `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`, is that not correct? Do I need to restart `Spark` (or reset anything else) so that updated properties are picked up?

Comment: Did you use the logger names already configured in the log4j.properties for Spark? Or maybe Spark uses log4j2 which has a different property file - log4j2.properties? If you can give more details, I can try to help

Comment: **@kjp** as far as I know, `Spark 2.3.0` (released 28th Feb, 2018) still uses `log4j` as told [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging). Additionally, what do you mean by *"logger names already configured in the log4j.properties for Spark"*? In the `log4j.properties` files I see lines like these `log4j.rootCategory=WARN,console` &
`log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`

Comment: Can you give a link to the full log4j config?

Comment: **@kjp** [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19aQVQtKafd7ZKaHsAKNm9luX5FcOLAKi)'s the link to my `/etc/spark/conf.dist/log4j.properties` file. Although I've downgraded to `Spark 2.2.1` (still on `EMR 5.12.0`), that doesn't seem to have any impact on this issue.