# Log4j config - different logs to different files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

This might be a very easy question for some, but personally I find Log4j config to be nightmarishly difficult and that learning to perform brain surgery might be less challenging.

I am trying to lave multiple loggers logging into different files.
Here is what I have  in my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, admin

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/nick/logging/file.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.admin=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.admin.File=/home/nick/logging/admin.log
log4j.appender.admin.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.admin.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.admin.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.admin.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

And here is my (very simple) Java app used to test the config:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties resource = new Properties();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/nick/logging/log4j.properties");
    resource.load(in);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(resource);

    Logger admin = Logger.getLogger("admin");
    Logger file = Logger.getLogger("file");

    admin.info("hello admin");
    file.info("hello file");
}
```

I have 2 problems:

One problem I always get an exception in the line `PropertyConfigurator.configure(resource);`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nick/logging (Is a directory)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
 at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
 at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
 at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
 at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
```

The 2nd problem is that both messages are written to both logs. Here is the **actual** result:

File admin:log:

```
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  admin - hello admin
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  file - hello file
```

File file.log:

```
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  admin - hello admin
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  file - hello file
```

Here is the **required** result:

File admin:log:

```
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  admin - hello admin
```

File file.log:

```
2014-04-27 11:55:30 INFO  file - hello file
```

What is causing the exception, and how can I achieve the required result?

Comment: Try with relative path `new FileInputStream("home/nick/logging/log4j.properties");`. remove first `/` to make it relative path.

Comment: one of the simplest solution is explained [here](https://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2018/11/writing-to-different-log-files-example.html)

Answer (score 127):

Log4J makes a distinction between *loggers*, which are responsible for generating log messages, and *appenders*, which are responsible for sending those messages somewhere (a file, the console, a database, etc.).  Loggers form a hierarchy, the root logger is the parent of the logger named `admin`, which is the parent of `admin.component1`, etc., and you can attach appenders to any logger in the hierarchy.  By default a logger will send messages to all appenders that are attached directly to it, or to any of its ancestors in the hierarchy (this is why loggers are conventionally named like Java classes, e.g. you can control logging for `com.example.Class1` and `com.example.subpkg.AnotherClass` by configuring the `com.example` logger).

Loggers and appenders form separate namespaces and this is the source of your confusion - the logger named `admin` and the appender named `admin` are two separate entities.

The configuration you have given in the question defines one logger (the root logger) which sends all the messages it generates to two separate *appenders*, one for each of the two files.  Your code then requests two different *loggers* and generates one log message with each logger.  Both these loggers inherit the appender configuration from the root logger, so they both send their messages to *both* of the configured appenders.

[image]

Instead of attaching the two appenders to the root logger, you should attach the `file` appender to the `file` logger and the `admin` appender to the `admin` logger:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.file=INFO, file
log4j.logger.admin=INFO, admin
```

This way the `file` logger will send messages only to `file.log`, the `admin` logger only to `admin.log`, and all messages from *other* loggers will be silently discarded, as there are no appenders attached to the root.

[image]

---

The *additivity* flag is the exception to this rule - setting a logger's additivity to false essentially disconnects the arrow from a logger up to its parent, so messages generated by that logger (or flowing into it from one of its children) will not go any further up the tree, they will only go to appenders attached *directly* to the logger in question.

Comment: This is the best explanation of loggers I have seen. It is very helpful.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much @Ian Roberts.  That was incredible.  CAN SOMEONE PLEASE MARK THIS AS ACCEPTED ANSWER!?!?!?

Answer (score 23):

To answer my own question, this is what I needed:

```
log4j.logger.file=DEBUG, fileAppender
log4j.logger.admin=DEBUG, adminAppender

log4j.additivity.file=false
log4j.additivity.admin=false

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=/home/nick/logging/file.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.adminAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.adminAppender.File=/home/nick/logging/admin.log
log4j.appender.adminAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.adminAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.adminAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.adminAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Answer (score 5):

**You don't need to load the properties file. Just place it inside the `src` folder that will automatically added in class path.**

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Logger admin = Logger.getLogger("admin");
   Logger file = Logger.getLogger("file");

   admin.info("hello admin");
   file.info("hello file");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - there was another log4j.properties in the src file and it was picking up that one, hence the exception. So that's sorted.But there's still the problem of both messages going to both files...

Comment: Have a look at [log4j-properties-examples](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)

Comment: Seen that already. I based my config on 3. Output to Console and File, but amended to be two different files.

Comment: Do you have multiple `log4j.properties` in the project?

Answer (score -1):

First: log4j recommands to use xml format file for properties.

Second: its better to load the properties file in the classloader.

Third: there is inheritance in logger, but you can cut it with additivity property see [log4j.properties file - multiple loggers in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240418/log4j-properties-file-multiple-loggers-in-same-class)

Comment: don't really understand what's going on there

Comment: Forget first and second you have your answer, take a look at additivity