# Not able to Log only my project logs using Log4j in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

This is my log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p
```

%c{1}:%L - %m%n

This is loading bunch of logs which are related to the framework etc.

I tried to put

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG only to load only my logs.
```

I want my log file to have only my project logs. Where should I need to change?

The way I'm logging my statements are

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

```
logger.debug("bla bla");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure `logger` as per  your application package name.

Suppose, your application package name is `test.example` then add below line in your `log4j.properties` -

```
log4j.logger.test.example = DEBUG, stdout, file
log4j.additivity.test.example = false
```

It will enable debug logs in classes which are present in `test.example` package as well as in sub packages.

For removing framework related logs, change `rootLogger` log level to `ERROR` or `WARN` -

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, file
```

It will display only errors which are related to framework classes or classes which are not present in above package `test.example` and its subpackages.

Comment: Vikas, this is not showing my own package logs too in console.

Comment: @Aliy what about file. Messages are getting logged in file ? How you are logging messages in your class ? Can you post one sample class.

Comment: Updated with logger statement too

Comment: @Aliy where is log4j.properties file is placed ? is it on classpath ? In question you mentioned that you are getting framework related logs. Those logs statement are debug logs ? and you are getting them in console and in file ?

Comment: properties file is directly placed under src. I'm getting logs of all packages inside it. I have some generated classes of web services, even those logs are getting printed both in console and file

Comment: @Aliy I am not sure what exactly the problem is with provided information. What I told you is standard and proper way to configuring logs. You can check more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240418/log4j-properties-file-multiple-loggers-in-same-class) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-additivity-property-example)

Comment: One point I would suggest to debug `log4j` using `log4j.debug` VM argument that would help to understand what is happening exactly

Answer (score -1):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,myproject

#My logger option
log4j.logger.com.myproject=ERROR
log4j.appender.myproject=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myprojectapp.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myproject.log
log4j.appender.myproject.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.myproject.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myproject.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -%M - %m%n
log4j.appender.myproject.Threshold=DEBUG

#to not add myproject logs to other logger
log4j.additivity.com.myproject=false
```